# How to Jest test if Firebase Analytics is called in ComponentDidMount in RN app

Tags: firebase, react-native, jestjs, firebase-analytics

I try to test a component starting with its componentDidMount function which calls `firebase.analytics().setCurrentScreen('Settings');`

Ok now here is how i mock `react-native-firebase` in jest.setup.js:

```
jest.mock('react-native-firebase', () => ({
  messaging: jest.fn(() => ({
    hasPermission: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
    subscribeToTopic: jest.fn(),
    unsubscribeFromTopic: jest.fn(),
    requestPermission: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true)),
    getToken: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('myMockToken')),
  })),
  notifications: jest.fn(() => ({
    onNotification: jest.fn(),
    onNotificationDisplayed: jest.fn(),
  })),
  analytics: jest.fn(() => ({
    logEvent: jest.fn(),
    setUserProperties: jest.fn(),
    setUserId: jest.fn(),
    setCurrentScreen: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));
```

here is my test:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {I18nextProvider} from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from 'config/i18nForTest';

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'
import {Settings} from 'containers/Settings'; // to get redux connected component import Setting without {}

it('is firebase.analytics().setCurrentScreen called in ComponentDidMount?', async () => {
  const setting = renderer.create(<Settings t={key => key} />).getInstance();
  await setting.componentDidMount();
  expect(firebase.analytics().setCurrentScreen).toBeCalled()
});
```

and finnaly the result of the test:

```
● is firebase.analytics().setCurrentScreen called in ComponentDidMount?

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      29 |   const setting = renderer.create(<Settings t={key => key} />).getInstance();
      30 |   await setting.componentDidMount();
    > 31 |   expect(firebase.analytics().setCurrentScreen).toBeCalled()//.mock.calls[0]).toEqual('Settings');
         |                                                                             ^
      32 | });
      33 | 

      at _callee2$ (__tests__/setting.test.js:31:77)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
      at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at invoke (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
      at node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:145:13
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
      at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
```